# Magento 2 : How to Change Order Of Billing and Shipping Address in Backend?

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, adminhtml, shipping-address, billing-address

we have requirement to change order of address fields like below at back-end order.

**Sort Order should be like below:**

- Street Address
- Country
- State/Province
- City
- Zip/Postal Code
- Phone Number

**Default/current address fields order is like below attached screen-shot**
[image]

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya : Do you have any solution for same? if you know any solution then please post here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On magento 2, you can override the Magento/Customer template. In our case, we have a custom copy of a Cleversoft theme so most of our overrides are done in the app/design/frontend file space.

In our case, we created the following directory heirarchy:

app/design/frontend/Cleversoft/custom/Magento_Customer/templates/address/

then copy the file from vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml into that folder. Edit the order and re-build. (magento setup:upgrade && magento setup:di:compile && magento setup:static-content:deploy)